# OS - How does OS map ready device data to respective processes

Tags: linux, operating-system

Let's take a hard drive/network interface. It is shared by multiple processes. Now multiple processes may issue concurrent commands to the hard drive to read data. When the data is available, how does the kernel know for which process has the data become ready? Is there some protocol followed between the OS and the hard drive. i.e. some metadata that is returned with the ready data?

Comment: 'Is there some protocol followed between the OS and the hard drive. i.e. some metadata that is returned with the ready data?' usually, yes, since the drive may well have consideraable buffering in itself and be concurrently servicing multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to data specific to each process (e.g. accessing file opened from filesystem on harddrive or receiving network) it is usually serialized using locking mechanisms. The "protocol" (assigning proper retrieved data to requesting process) is afaik more or less driver or kernel part specific - done differently in e.g. networking code and virtual file system code.

This is very well described in chapter called "Concurrency and Race Conditions" of Linux Device Drivers book by Kroah-Hartman, Rubini, Corbet. You can take a look here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch05.html